# Macro doesn't work after 32367 lines in 2010 excel

Tags: vba, excel, large-data

I have 90,000+ lines of data to consolidate. My code works fine with up to 25k lines or so. But when there is more data, it stops at 32267 line and says object error.

I have referred few of Stackoverflow reviews on same model. But the answers in them didn't help my concern.

My Code

```
Sub macro_consolidator()

Dim spendSheet As Worksheet
Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim spendLastRow As Long
Dim outputLastRow As Long
Dim spendID As String
Dim outputIDRow As Variant
Dim ctSheet As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet, flg As Boolean
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set spendSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
For Each sh In Worksheets
If sh.Name Like "Output" Then flg = True: Exit For
Next
If flg = False Then
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = "Output"

   Set outputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("output")
   Set spendSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    spendLastRow = spendSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

  outputLastRow = outputSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = 4 To spendLastRow  

   spendID = CStr(spendSheet.Cells(i, 3)) + CStr(spendSheet.Cells(i, 4)) + CStr(spendSheet.Cells(i, 5)) + CStr(spendSheet.Cells(i, 6)) + CStr(spendSheet.Cells(i, 10)) + CStr(spendSheet.Cells(i, 15)) + CStr(spendSheet.Cells(i, 16))

outputIDRow = Application.Match(spendID, outputSheet.Columns(35), 0)
    If Not IsError(outputIDRow) Then
            outputSheet.Cells(outputIDRow, 11) = spendSheet.Cells(i, 14)
            outputSheet.Cells(outputIDRow, 12) = outputSheet.Cells(outputIDRow, 12) + spendSheet.Cells(i, 13) ' Actual Spend - Addition wit previous

            If spendSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "CORPORATE" Then
            MsgBox (outputIDRow):
            outputSheet.Cells(outputIDRow, 14) = outputSheet.Cells(outputIDRow, 14) + spendSheet.Cells(i, 9)
            End If
            If spendSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "CCP" Then

                outputSheet.Cells(outputIDRow, 13) = outputSheet.Cells(outputIDRow, 13) + spendSheet.Cells(i, 9)
            End If
            If spendSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "FAB 2" Then

                outputSheet.Cells(outputIDRow, 15) = outputSheet.Cells(outputIDRow, 15) + spendSheet.Cells(i, 9)
            End If
            If spendSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "FAB 3" Then
                outputSheet.Cells(outputIDRow, 16) = outputSheet.Cells(outputIDRow, 16) + spendSheet.Cells(i, 9)
            End If
            If spendSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "FAB 3E" Then
                outputSheet.Cells(outputIDRow, 17) = outputSheet.Cells(outputIDRow, 17) + spendSheet.Cells(i, 9)
            End If
            If spendSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "FAB 5" Then
                outputSheet.Cells(outputIDRow, 18) = outputSheet.Cells(outputIDRow, 18) + spendSheet.Cells(i, 9)
            End If
            If spendSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "FAB 6" Then
                outputSheet.Cells(outputIDRow, 19) = outputSheet.Cells(outputIDRow, 19) + spendSheet.Cells(i, 9)
            End If
            If spendSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "FAB 7" Then
                outputSheet.Cells(outputIDRow, 20) = outputSheet.Cells(outputIDRow, 20) + spendSheet.Cells(i, 9)
            End If
               ' MsgBox (outputSheet.Cells(3, 13))

    Else
        outputLastRow = outputLastRow + 1
        outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 35) = spendID
        outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 1) = spendSheet.Cells(i, 2)
        outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 2) = spendSheet.Cells(i, 5)
        outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 3) = spendSheet.Cells(i, 4) ' was (i,5)
        outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 4) = spendSheet.Cells(i, 10)
        outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 5) = spendSheet.Cells(i, 16)
        outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 6) = spendSheet.Cells(i, 15)
        outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 7) = spendSheet.Cells(i, 6)
        'outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 8) = spendSheet.Cells(i, 14)
       ' outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 9) = spendSheet.Cells(i, 11)
        outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 10) = spendSheet.Cells(i, 3)
        outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 11) = spendSheet.Cells(i, 14) ' Unit Price
        outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 12) = spendSheet.Cells(i, 13) ' Actual USD
        'outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 13) = outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 13) + spendSheet.Cells(i, 19)
       ' outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 13) = spendSheet.Cells(i, 19)

            If spendSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "CORPORATE" Then
               MsgBox (outputLastRow):
                outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 14) = outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 14) + spendSheet.Cells(i, 9)
            End If
            If spendSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "CCP" Then
                outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 13) = outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 13) + spendSheet.Cells(i, 9)
            End If
            If spendSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "FAB 2" Then
                outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 15) = outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 15) + spendSheet.Cells(i, 9)
            End If
            If spendSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "FAB 3" Then
                outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 16) = outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 16) + spendSheet.Cells(i, 9)
            End If
            If spendSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "FAB 3E" Then
                outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 17) = outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 17) + spendSheet.Cells(i, 9)
            End If
            If spendSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "FAB 5" Then
                outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 18) = outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 18) + spendSheet.Cells(i, 9)
            End If
            If spendSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "FAB 6" Then
                outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 19) = outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 19) + spendSheet.Cells(i, 9)
            End If
            If spendSheet.Cells(i, 1) = "FAB 7" Then
                outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 20) = outputSheet.Cells(outputLastRow, 20) + spendSheet.Cells(i, 9)
            End If

    End If
 Next i

 End Sub
```

Comment: Your code has a missing `End If`. If it doesn't compile it makes it hard to answer!

Comment: 32267 ?? I believe, it's the maximum length of an excell file. Not sure, but search for 'maximum length excell file' ..